# Percentage for different APIs in a thread group in jmeter

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a thread group in which there are 4 APIs. Now, I want to control the TPS of these APIs. For that, lets say these should be the TPS of these APIs:

```
API#1: 10
API#2: 20
API#3: 30
API#4: 40
```

Now, for this total number of requests is 100. hence the percentage of these APIs are 10%, 20%, 30% and 40%. How, can I enable this in my jmeter test plan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use 4 [Throughput Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) and give the desired percentage of executions in them:

   [image]
2. You can put the requests under different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and set number of users and/or iterations according to your test scenario:

   [image]
3. You can use [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/weighted-switch-controller-jmeter) and provide the desired "weights" for the API endpoints there:

   [image]